# How do I stop visual studio inserting a space between function definition and immediate call?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, jslint

I am using the visual studio JSLint plugin to keep my javascript in order, which seems to work really well apart from this one problem.

If I type in

```
x = (function () {
}())
```

And then put the semicolon on the end, Visual studio corrects it to:

```
x = (function () {
} ());
```

And then JSLint complains `JS Lint: Unexpected space between '}' and '('.`

Obviously this is fixable by removing the space, but visual studio is very persistent in putting the space back. Putting a semicolon anywhere inside the function, which is most of the file, will cause VS to put the space back. This is starting to get annoying.

I've tried mucking about with the visual studio Javascript editor settings ('insert space after...'), but can't seem to stop it doing this.

Another way this could be expressed is

```
x = (function () {
})();
```

Which VS leaves alone, but JSLint says `JS Lint: Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function.` So no dice there.

Any suggestions? I know I can turn bits of JSLint off, even just around this last line of the file, but that's going to look messy, I'd like to do a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a better response than turning off whitespace formatting rule checking, but this is very unfortunate. As far as I can tell, this one situation described here is the only case were visual studio automatic formatting and jslint collide in a way you can't reasonable config your way out of.

Losing the entire whitespace checking for this source file, or losing the auto reformatting of the rest of your JavaScript, are both somewhat sledgehammer approaches to this problem.  I'd love to see another creative option if anyone has one.

Answer (score 11):

UPDATED ANSWER FOR VS 2013:

In VS 2013, we seem to have more control.  Go to Tools > Options window, then under Text Editor > Javascript > Formatting > Spacing you can deselect the second-to-last option that says "Insert space after function keyword for anonymous functions."

I had a pic but I can't post it :).

Comment: The user asked about VS2010 specifically. VS-2012/13 added much greater support of Javascript but that is not what this question is about...

Comment: True, but in 2011 VS2010 was all you had.  I googled this in 2014 needing to know the same thing.  Of course, if I posted a new question about it I'd probably get flagged for asking a duplicate.

Comment: @BrianBarker you did the right thing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

First of all you can make Visual Studio not so persistent if you switch off some default settings:

[image]

Another way is to follow not so exact the formatting rules of JSlint. You can just include

```
/*jslint white: true */
```

to switch off the [white space](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) formatting rule.